# Validate an Email with a Regex expression in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, email

See, I have the below simple regexp to validate an Email value.

```
^(|(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$
```

and when I run the same, it works! http://rubular.com/r/O3EDkx5a8t

See, I have an Excel file which contains `Name`, `Email` columns. While importing I need to validate Email id's, otherwise skip those rows from importing. I've done importing and all except this validation.

Now if I have the Email value in `row["Email"]` variable, suppose '`abc@gmail.com`' How can I validate and confirm that the Emails are properly formatted?

I've seen `match`, `scan` methods for string matching using `Regex`. But, I'm not aware how to fit those in this context. When validating it should return `true` if it is a proper email, other wise it should return `false`. Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I found the answer:

```
2.0.0-p247 :022 > "%_@gmail.com" =~ /^(|(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$/
 => nil 
2.0.0-p247 :023 > "a@gmail.com" =~ /^(|(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$/
 => 0
```

When `Email` is proper, it will return `0`, otherwise `nil`.

Thanks :)